# How can I have a label span across a set of columns in Stack Exchange's MathJax?

Tags: arrays, mathjax

I'm from [another Stack Exchange site](//rpg.stackexchange.com/) where we've just had MathJax enabled. There's a table [in this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/76983/1204) that looks like this (actual decimals just typed in for the example), which looks rather pretty, except the rows and columns are unlabelled:

```
\begin{array}{r|lll}
  & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
0 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.168 \\
1 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.168 \\
2 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.168
\end{array}
```

[image]

If I want to label the headings and columns, my attempts go awry due to stretching out the first column:

```
\begin{array}{r|lll}
& \text{number of foo} \\
\text{number of bar} & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
```

[image]

... clearly that's not the way to do it. Googling has turned up `\multicolumn`, but that's a thing for tables which aren't available in the Stack's MathJax.

I've considered I could just use a bunch of spacing to finagle the label into just the right position. It looks nice, but I don't know if there's a way I "should" be doing it or could bear in mind for the future:

```
\,\,\quad\qquad\qquad \text{number of foo} \rightarrow \\
\begin{array}{r|lll}
\text{number of bar}  & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
```

[image]

**Is there an appropriate, robust and good-looking way to place a label across a set of columns?** I'm open to using an environment other than array, if it does the job of displaying that data in a tabular form and works within [our Stack Exchange MathJax environment](//rpg.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As your posting appears to be about MathJax rather than TeX, LaTeX, and friends, it may be off-topic for this site. MathJaX has syntax elements that are borrowed from LaTeX, but it uses a completely different rendering engine.

Comment: @MIco Oh, thanks, now I see the last part of that tag's summary. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put the column labels inside a `r`ight over`lap`, which effectively puts it inside a zero-width box that is left-aligned:

```
$$
  \begin{array}{r|lll}
    & \rlap{\text{number of foo}} \\
    \text{number of bar} & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
    \hline
    0 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.168 \\
    1 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.168 \\
    2 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.168
  \end{array}
$$
```

Here is the output on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com):

[image]